# Inconsistent behavior for complex NA?

Tags: r

I find R's handling of `NA` for complex variables to be unintuitive:

```
z <- complex(real      = c( 1,  1, NA, NA, NA),
             imaginary = c(NA, NA,  1,  1, NA))

print(z)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

Re(z)
#> [1]  1  1 NA NA NA

Im(z)
#> [1] NA NA  1  1 NA

unique(z)
#> [1] NA

Re(unique(z))
#> [1] 1

identical(z[1], z[3])
#> FALSE
```

Are all of these behaviors as designed? If not, which of these are bugs?

---

### Straw man proposal

Here's a straw man proposal. I'm not crazy about it, but it leads to consistent behavior:

It looks like the R developers have decided that conceptually, there is only one complex `NA` value, but it has many different representations. These representations are the complex numbers with `NA` in the binary representation for the real or imaginary part.

To maintain consistency in this "equivalent representations" world, if `z1` and `z2` are two different representations of complex `NA`, then `f(z1)` and `f(z2)` should return equivalent results for all functions `f`.

In this case, the above behavior for `print(z)` and `unique(z)` is correct.

The other behavior should be as follows:

```
Re(z)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

Im(z)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

Re(unique(z))
#> [1] NA

identical(z[1], z[3])
#> TRUE
```

The only operation that should look at the binary representation of the values is `identical` with `single.NA` set to `FALSE`:

```
identical(z[1], z[3], single.NA = FALSE)
#> FALSE
```

Comment: for starters, I'd say that the behavior of `identical` is not surprinsing. Elemts 1 and 3 of `z` are definetely not "exactly identical".

Comment: The only one that seems surprising to me is `Re(unique(z))`, which I suspect is due to something odd that unique() is doing, but I'm still digging a little.

Comment: Yeah, so `unique()` is treating the vector `z` as having only one "unique" values, `NA` (i.e. `NA_complex_`) and hence `unique()` just spits out the first element. So you get the real part of whichever one was first. Personally, I wouldn't consider this a bug, although I can see how it would be surprising. But "uniqueness" in this case is sort of orthogonal to the specific real/imaginary parts of each element.

Comment: unique returns only the first element of `z` (ignoring all the `NA` in`real` and the first element of `Re(z)`is `NA`, so thats not so surprising either.

Comment: R is reading `z[5]` as `NA_complex_` but `z[1:4]` are a bit different.  You can look at `identical(Re(z[3]), NA_real_)` and `identical(Im(z[1]), NA_real_)` for more intuition.  Does anyone know the type of `NA` that R is classifying `z[1:4]`?

Comment: I take it back (partially). I'm not quite sure what R is doing with those first 4 values in z.

Comment: From the `complex()` documentation:
Operations and functions involving complex NaN mostly rely on the C library's handling of double complex arithmetic, which typically returns complex(re=NaN, im=NaN) (but we have not seen a guarantee for that). For + and -, R's own handling works strictly “coordinate wise”.

Comment: in `unique.c` R source code: `if (R_IsNA(ans.r) || R_IsNA(ans.i)) ans.r = ans.i = NA_REAL;`